# Is it possible to combine dataframes from two separate programs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

Possibly a stupid question, but I'm very new. I have two separate large-ish (a couple million rows) csvs I'm trying to compare using dataframe functionality and I'm currently working on cleaning them in two separate programs due to the way I was onboarded. Is it possible to combine the two dataframes (once they're cleaned) without having to import both csvs into one program as dataframes, clean them, and then combine them? Basically, is it possible to reach across programs to combine dataframes?

I'm expecting this work like importing pyIS or pandas, but I haven't tried it yet for fear of breaking something (like my laptop). I'm a bit scared of accidentally erasing something I shouldn't or making another intern-esque mistake.

Comment: You might be looking for something like [pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)

Comment: Can you import both programs as modules into a main program? it can then load each df into a variable, call the appropriate cleaning code, then merge them.